# python dataframe std deviation of a column/row containing all Nan values except one element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, standard-deviation

I have a python dataframe like this

```
In [212]: d3  
Out[212]: 
     a    b    c    d    e  
a  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
b  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  
c  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  
d  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  
e  3.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  
f  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  0.0  
p  NaN  3.0  NaN  3.0  NaN  
q  NaN  4.0  4.0  4.0  NaN  
r  NaN  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

And when I find standard deviation using `d3.std(axis=1)`, I get SD of row 'r' is **NaN** and I was expecting **0** for the same.

```
In [213]: d3.std(axis=1)
Out[213]:
a    0.000000
b    0.000000
c    0.000000
d    0.000000
e    0.447214
f    2.236068
p    0.000000
q    0.000000
r         NaN
dtype: float64
```

When I try the same using numpy's `nanstd()` function this gives me desired result.

```
In [225]: np.nanstd(d3.loc['r',:])
Out[225]: 0.0
```

But I have a dataframe and I want to use dataframe's std function like this `d3['new_col']=np.where(d3.std(axis=1)==0, d3.min(axis=1), np.nan)`
this results into

```
In [226]: d3['new_col'] = np.where(d3.std(axis=1)==0, d3.min(axis=1), np.nan)

In [227]: d3
Out[227]:
     a    b    c    d    e  new_col
a  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0
b  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0      1.0
c  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0      2.0
d  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0      3.0
e  3.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0      NaN
f  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  0.0      NaN
p  NaN  3.0  NaN  3.0  NaN      3.0
q  NaN  4.0  4.0  4.0  NaN      4.0
r  NaN  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
```

I am expecting rightmost bottom most value to be **5.0** not **NaN**.

Comment: See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html -> "Normalized by N-1 by default.". If you have 1 element you're doing a division by 0.